# Why is Referenced Component not be found in Visual Studio 2017 when it is found in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with two projects - a primary project, and a unit test project.  When opening in Visual Studio 2015 all references are found and project builds successfully.  When opening in Visual Studio 2017 several but not all NuGet package references are not found and compile fails.  Some of the failed references are...

- System.Data.Common
- System.Net.Http
- System.Net.Http.WebRequest
- System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms
- System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding
- System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives
- System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

[image: References]

... but other NuGet references are found with no problem.  This solution was created with VS2015.  When viewing the .csproj file nothing out of the ordinary is jumping out.

I am thinking of rebuilding it from scratch in VS2017 to try to identify the problem.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, and/or has anyone any suggestions on why this is occurring and what should be done to facilitate a fix?

**Update:**
I created a brand new VS2017 WebApi project referencing .NET 4.7.1, and compiled successfully.  I then added NuGet package System.Data.Common 4.3.0.  The NuGet install process appears to have completed with no errors, but still I am left with an invalid reference.  That was pretty easy to replicate.

Comment: Did you run a `nuget restore` before compiling? It should do it as part of the build process, maybe something is strange in your .sln or csproj file.

Comment: @RonBeyer - I performed Update-Package -reinstall, but did not try nuget restore.  I assumed the reinstall would be sufficient but perhaps not....

Comment: FYI - dont know if it has anything to do with it - I tried to manually Add the reference to a simple 4.7.1 Console Application and for some reason he changed the path to the following `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.1\Facades\System.Data.Common.dll` though I picked the file from the Nuget Packages Folder - for me it seems like 4.7.1 just simply doesnt want the nuget package

Comment: @RandRandom - Looks like System.Data.Common namespace is now found in System.Data.dll, and does not need this NuGet package.  I added an answer to this question with this specific info...

Comment: This solved my problem: delete bin/obj folders and build. Not sure why but all the warnings vanished for the references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, answering my own question.

I found what I believe is the answer.  This particular project was originally developed in VS2015 using .NET 4.6.2.  When changing to VS2017 we elected to upgrade .NET to 4.7.1.  The problem is with the .NET version, not the VS version.

The newer version of .NET has many of these NuGet assemblies added to standard libraries.  The NuGet packages were in conflict with the native .NET 4.7.1 namespaces.  For example, in .NET 4.7.1, the namespace System.Data.Common is found in the assembly System.Data.dll.  No longer is it required to add a NuGet assembly System.Data.Common.dll.  In fact, if I do add System.Data.Common NuGet package assembly, I now have two assemblies having the namespace System.Data.Common - one in System.Data.dll and another in System.Data.Common.dll - hence the reference problem.

The solution is to use the .NET 4.7.1 version and remove the extra NuGet assembly.  This was also true for System.Security conflicts.  The conflict with System.Net.Http was actually moved into a NuGet assembly called Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.

I hope all of this helps someone else...(uhhhgggg)....

**BTW** - it appears that when using VS2015 with .NET 4.7.1, these conflicts are suppressed and never display.  This feels like a shortcoming of VS2015.  Glad VS2017 shows them to reveal the true problem...

Answer (score 0):

Check your `packages.config` file to make sure the Nuget packages are actually listed as dependencies for your project.

Also, open the solution in VS 2015 and double check the file path for the references in question. Make sure the DLLs are not referenced from a file path unique to Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: both valid points.  I have verified the packages.config file is accurate.  In fact, I have removed and re-added the NuGet packages multiple times trying to square this up.  My paths are relative.  Here is an example of entry in the .csproj file for System.Data.Common (see next comment)

Comment: <Reference Include="System.Data.Common, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Data.Common.4.3.0\lib\net451\System.Data.Common.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new project and transfer all the necessary files from the old project to new project to fix this.